# PHP PATCH Product PayPal Catalog API Malformed request error

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have an issue which is driving me nuts. I'm trying to update a Product using the PayPal Catalog API. It's a fairly basic cURL call using the code below:

```
$authorization="Authorization: Bearer ".$authorization;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products/RBW00002');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"op": "replace", "path": "/description", "value": "xxx"}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = $authorization;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

$editproduct= json_decode($result);

print_r($editproduct );
echo "<br><br>";

print_r($json);
echo "<br><br>";

unset($headers);
curl_close($ch);
```

but it keeps coming back with the following error:

> stdClass Object ( [name] => INVALID_REQUEST [message] => Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema. [debug_id] => 70cc270a1a2a1 [details] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [field] => / [location] => body [issue] => MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON [description] => The request JSON is not well formed. ) ) [links] => Array ( )

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: How does `$ch` look?

Comment: As both echo or print_r() it says 'Resource id #7'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [Update product details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/product-management/#update-product-details), the top level item should be an array with `[]` brackets

```
'[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/description",
    "value": "Premium video streaming service"
  }
]'
```

Comment: Correct, but the documentation shows an example of a direct cURL call whereas I'm using the curl object in PHP, in which case the POSTFIELDS string is constructed to form a JSON array. This verifies OK a https://jsonlint.com/ so I'm not sure that's the problem. And I did a similar POST call using a the same sort of string.

Comment: The specification states the request body must be an *array* of patch objects https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/catalog-products/v1/#products_patch  -- so yes, it's the problem.

Comment: I beg your pardon! You were right! I have not seen an example of this anywhere with square brackets in the string, unless I'm going blind. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Preston PHX
please help me with this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081641/add-div-tag-inside-all-li-with-matching-class-name-using-php/64092865#64092865